# What is the probability that 3 points chosen at random inside a circle form an acute triangle

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry

Please note that it is INSIDE, not ON the circumference!
This question has been adressed in the litterature, by Glen Hall, but I can't find papers.
It seems that the answer is $$\frac{4}{\pi^2}-\frac{1}{8}$$ but with my computations, it gives something different $$\frac{44-4\pi}{45\pi}$$! I'm certainly wrong! 
Help would be welcome!

Comment: What *are* your computations?

Comment: Are your computations a model?

Comment: Is it possible that your computations assume a non-uniform distribution for the points? E.g., if you pick a random radius and a random angle, you will get a higher density of points nearer the centre, and this will (barring surprising coincidences) change the answer.

Comment: I believe the question can be simplified to:  
What is the probability that two chords intersect at an angle less than $90^\circ$ however something feels off about my phrasing...

Comment: I ran a simulation and got 72.0% +- 0.2% obtuse and 28.0% +- 0.2% acute.

Comment: I ran a larger simulation with 4 million triangles and got 28.039% were acute (standard error 0.02%).  Glen Hall's answer evaluates to approximately 28.0285%.  Your answer comes out to 22.2%.

Comment: Here is a reference with a proof (even for larger dimensions) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallTrianglePicking.html